# Multiple combo boxes added to the FlowLayoutPanel dynamically, if I onchange of one combo box remaining also affected

Tags: c#, winforms

I added multiple combo boxes to the FlowLayoutPanel dynamically. If I receive an `onchange` on one, the combo boxes remaining are also affected. I don't want to affect the remaining combo boxes. What should I do?

```
 foreach(var video in videos) 
{
    var subvideos = video.Descendants("subvideos");
    if (subvideos.Count() >= 1) 
    {
        ComboBox subvideo = new ComboBox();
        subvideo.Name = "subvideo" + i;
        subvideo.Items.Add(video.Attribute("name").Value);
        foreach(var videoname in subvideos) 
        {
            subvideo.Items.Add(videoname.Value);
        }
        flowlayoutpanel1.Controls.Add(subvideo);
        i++;
    } 
    else 
    {
        var text = new TextBox();
        text.Text = video.Attribute("name").Value;
        flowlayoutpanel1.Controls.Add(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the on change event definition?

Comment: in flow layout panel its displaying multiple combo boxes,suppose if i select the 2nd item present in one combo box automatically in remaining combo boxes  2nd item is displaying

Comment: Why the question again? I was asking for the event definition in the back end `private sub combo_SelectedIndexChange()`

Comment: i didn't define the selectedindex change function

Comment: @un-lucky no possible private sub's its c# not vb

Comment: Then this `foreach(var video in videos){//}` belongs to which method?

Comment: it belongs to combo box if i select the chapter name in that combo box it has to display the videos,if that videos has sub videos it has to display like a combo box .

Comment: there is no change event coupled to any of the comboboxes, so you do not receive an onchange event and there is no problem. Unless you left out the only part of code that we need to help you, the assigning of the change events...